# Find the center of mass R:

Tags: calculus

Let R be a solid with a constant density, determined by the three inequalities 
$
5-x^2-y^2 \geq z,  x^2+y^2-(z+1)^2 \leq 0 ,  z \geq 0 
$

Find the center of mass of R.

Can anyone tell me how to integral over that domain?

Comment: You might want to consider cylindrical coordinates. This is going to take a triple integral, which usually acts like nested integrals where the bounds are related to the variables of the next integral. In this case you want to integrate the density (d) over a series of regions. But putting those regions in cylindrical (or possibly spherical) coordinates could help make the bounds come out more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have a constant density it will not come into the centre of mass calculation and we may take it as $1$.

By drawing a diagram you can see that to integrate in cylindrical coordinates we will have to split the integral into two parts:
$$0\le r\le1\,,\ 0\le z\le 5-r^2\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  1\le r\le2\,,\ r-1\le z\le 5-r^2\ .$$
So, calculate the mass
$$M=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{5-r^2} r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta+
  \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2\int_{r-1}^{5-r^2} r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta\ ,$$
and then the $z$-coordinate of the centre of mass is
$$\overline z=\frac{1}{M}\Bigl(\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{5-r^2} zr\,dz\,dr\,d\theta+
  \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2\int_{r-1}^{5-r^2} zr\,dz\,dr\,d\theta\Bigr)\ .$$
If you carefully consider the shape of the solid, you should be able to write down $\overline x$ and $\overline y$ without calculation.

Comment: That is a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Misread the question, my bad.  The below is for finding the mass.

Consider a transform to cylindrical coordinates. (x,y,z) goes to (r, $\theta$, z). 
So now our relations are: $ 5 - r^2 \geq z, r^2 - (z+1)^2 \leq 0, z \geq 0$
Thus, we need to determine what the bounds for r are. The bounds for $\theta$ are 0 to $2*\pi$ because we have circular symmetry.
We can conclude that $r \leq z+1$ because z must be non-negative. By substitution, 
$r \leq 5 - r^2 +1 = 6 - r^2$ Since $r^2 +r \leq 6$ we must conclude (by quadratic formula) that $r \leq 2$. 
Let P be the density.
Now we need $\int_0^{2*\pi} \! \int_0^2 \! \int_0^{r-1} \! P \, \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta$. Since P is not dependent on anything, we get $\int_0^{2*\pi} \! \int_0^2 \! P*(r-1) \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta$ = $\int_0^{2*\pi} \! P*(\frac{r^2 , 2} - r)\, \mathrm{d}\theta = 2*\pi * P*(\frac{r^2 , 2} - r)$

Comment: Don't forget the Jacobian $r$ in the integral.